# Legend and TraMiner seqplot.tentrop function

Tags: r, traminer

I have a problem with the legend of a TraMineR graph.

I have computed the 4 different entropies for the 4 cohorts that I'm analyzing and I would like to plot them in the same graph using the `seqplot.tentrop` function. However, the default legend is too big and I would plot it separately reducing the dimensions, but I can't reproduce the colors of the legend in the new one I've created with the last command below.

```
    plot_colors <- c("blue", "red", "forestgreen", "purple")
    seqplot.tentrop(myseq, group = job$cohort, ylim = c(0, 1), 
      col=plot_colors, withlegend=FALSE)
    legend("bottomright", names(myseq), 
      c("1974-1978","1982-1986","1990-1994", "1998-2001"),
      cex=0.8, col=plot_colors)
```

Is it possible to change colors/dotted lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to make it clear, the `seqplot.tentrop` function is currently provided by the `TraMineRextras` package, not `TraMineR`.

Now regarding your problem. You are in trouble because you don't provide the line types to `legend()`. Function `seqplot.tentrop` assigns default line tyes. You can override them to be sure to use the same ones for the plot and the legend. Here is how your code should look out:

```
plot_colors <- c("blue", "red", "forestgreen", "purple") 
plot_lty <-  c("solid","dashed","dotted","solid") 
seqplot.tentrop(myseq, group = job$cohort, ylim = c(0, 1), 
       lty=plot_lty, col=plot_colors, withlegend=FALSE)

legend("bottomright",
       legend=c("1974-1978","1982-1986","1990-1994","1998-2001"),           
       cex=0.8, lty=plot_lty, col=plot_colors)
```

Furthermore, it may be useful to control the line thickness with the `lwd` argument. For example, `lwd=2` would double the line thickness.